# Simple command that switches between two host files

Tags: alias, hosts

I am using /etc/host to map localhost to a web domain. I would like a fast way of doing this rather than searching and replacing every time. I put this in my .bashrc file.

```
alias hostchange='
nowdir=$PWD;
cd /etc;
mv hosts hoststempname;
mv hostssecondary hosts;
mv hoststempname hostssecondary;
cd $nowdir'
```

I am getting this error and it won't progress regardless y or n.

```
mv: rename hosts to hoststempname: Permission denied
override rw-r--r--  root/wheel for hosts? (y/n [n])
```

I got it to work by adding sudo.

```
alias hostchange='
nowdir=$PWD;
cd /etc;
sudo mv hosts hoststempname;
sudo mv hostssecondary hosts;
sudo mv hoststempname hostssecondary;
cd $nowdir'
```

Is this legitimate, I'm taking a shot in the dark here?

Comment: *I'll try to be as little offensive as I can - sorry if it is still too much.* In order to get an answer that can be useful to you, please write what basic information about linux/unix you posses. Specifically, in the areas of *user accounts*, *file ownership* and *file permissions*.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll be sure to include this info next time: (Mac 10.6.5 (unix | bash) / Admin) Does that help?

Comment: Uhm... No, I simply can't believe the *Admin* part. What admin does not understand the bare **minimum** of file ownerships and permissions?

Comment: What are you getting at? Its my computer and I'm the only user, what does file ownership & permissions have to do with anything???

Comment: Ok. I see. You just have no idea about the concept of *nix users. I'll try to get over it somehow... Just please, don't call yourself admin.

Comment: What I ment by `admin` is that yes I do have `superuser` control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track!  A couple comments about this.  It is usually better practice to leave multi-line actions like this to functions.  I'd probably write it like this:

```
change_etc_hosts_file() {
  set -e # stop running if we encounter an error
  sudo \mv -f /etc/hosts /etc/hoststempname
  sudo \mv -f /etc/hostssecondary /etc/hosts
  sudo \mv -f /etc/hoststempname /etc/hostssecondary
  set +e
}
alias changehosts=change_etc_hosts_file
```

You'll notice I also used absolute paths instead of changing directory.  This is usually a better idea (to use absolute paths).  If you do want to keep using relatives then it is usually better to do that in a sub-shell so you don't have to handling changing directory back to $PWD (which if you abort will leave you in a weird state).  To do it as a sub-shell it would look like this:

```
change_etc_hosts_file() {
  ( # use subshell
    cd /etc
    set -e # stop running if we encounter an error
    sudo \rm -f hoststempname # the \ escapes aliases which might cause prompting
    sudo \cp -f hosts hoststempname
    sudo \cp -f hostssecondary hosts
    sudo \cp -f hoststempname hostssecondary
  )
}
```

The cd happens inside the () which is a new process so it won't affect your current working directory.

Comment: +1 for answering the question earnestly without patronizing comments regarding lack of sudo understanding

Answer (score 0):

<sub>The fact of you having doubts about the `sudo` command shows that somehow you survived so far in the Unix world without possessing the basic knowledge about the concept of unix users (**root** especially). Although this situation is incomprehensible to me, your question along with the comments clearly indicate that is the case.</sub>

**Yes**, what you achieved with `sudo` is just what is expected. This is because:

- On Unix systems, there is a number of *system users* - you can call them 'virtual' (these are **not** to be mistaken with human *computer users*).
- Each file and directory has it's **owner**, which is always one of the (virtual) users.
- The **root** user, known as *superuser* is the special system account every Unix has to have. He can do everything - has full power over the system.
- `sudo` is a command used to temporarily leverage "normal" user's privileges to *root* so that some special tasks can be performed.

**Do have a further read** about root, `sudo` and file permissions on these example sites: **[1](http://www.linux-corner.info/sudo.html)**, **[2](http://www.northernjourney.com/opensource/newbies/newb006.html)**, **[3](http://linuxaria.com/howto/sudo_howto?lang=en)**, **[4](http://linuxreviews.org/beginner/#toc4)**, **[5](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/36845/the-beginners-guide-to-managing-users-and-groups-in-linux/)**, **[6](http://www.basicconfig.com/linux/ownership)**

Comment: I understand what you are getting at, however what confused me was how `sudo` would run within an `alias` and how `unix` would handle the password request process. I have used `sudo` before. I had no experience with how `sudo` would behave within an `alias`. Moreover that when `sudo` was run more than once within a command it wouldn't break the command and ask for the password before it finished the command. Thanks for your through clarification on `sudo` and expressing your concerns.