# Trying to setup sudo user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, sudoedit

I'm trying to setup `sudo` with no password but still I get prompted for password.

I'm using Ubuntu, here is the relevant line from the sudoers configuration file :

```
gandalf ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Drop the ":ALL" inside the parentheses and your syntax is correct.  Therefore, the problem must be elsewhere: wrong username (execute `id` to see what the system thinks it is), other configuration line for *gandalf* that overrides this one, invisible character in the file (for example, it was copy/pasted from a Windows word processor), and so on.  Given that you logged in here as `Gandalf`, could it be that your Linux username also uses a capital-G?

Answer (score 2):

Try dropping the extra :ALL, example:

`gandalf ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: But still I have to type in password .. when I open/close terminal

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "when I open/close terminal"?

Comment: Well there is icon terminal I click on it the terminal pops out I issue the `sudo command` and I get prompted for password. After I type the password I no longer get prompted. Then I click on the x standard for quiting from any program and re-open terminal and again prompted for password

Comment: Your desktop is running under the user gandalf correct? Is the system user spelled the same way (hint: Linux user names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have other rules in your `sudoers` file, by any chance? The rules are applied in order, so if you have a rule allowing you to run a command with a password prompt followed by another rule that allows you to run the command without a password prompt, you'll have to type the password. Put the no-password rule first.

See [Why is sudo telling me my password is wrong?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23543/why-is-sudo-telling-me-my-password-is-wrong/23793#23793)

Answer (score 0):

My "man sudoers" on ubuntu contains this example line

```
FULLTIMERS ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

FULLTIMERS is an alias rather than a user, but it should still work if you put a user name there. As far as I know, NOPASSWD: has to come before the first mention of ALL (after the equals sign) to bind to it.

Comment: But still I have to type in password .. when I open/close terminal

Comment: How exactly are you opening the terminal - is it a link in the menu, or something else?
If you open a shell and type "sudo ls" in there, does it still ask for a password?
(What I suspect is that your command to open/close terminal is actually doing something other than just calling sudo.)

Comment: Well there is icon terminal I click on it the terminal pops out I issue the `sudo command` and I get prompted for password. After I type the password I no longer get prompted. Then I click on the x standard for quiting from any program and re-open terminal and again prompted for password

Answer (score 0):

I use a group call `sudo` and have the line

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

which seems to work.